# New line being inserted before rendering the text box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code snippet; but I am not sure why a newline character (a `<br>` tag to be precise) is added between Email and its corresponding text box:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>My Website!</h3>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<form>
  <div class="form-group" align="center">
    <div class="input-group" style="width=5px">

      <center>
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email: </span>
        <input class="form-control" align="center" type="text" id="EmailId" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" align="center">
    <div class="input-group">
      <center>
        <label for="Password"></label>Password:
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="PasswordId" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login!</button>
</form>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The output being displayed is:

[image]

What changes must be done so that it is displayed on the same line?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zuzidek/1/edit?html,output — It isn't, at least not with the code in your question. Your [mcve] does not appear to be complete or verifiable.

Comment: where's thy CSS

Comment: @Quentin, I have pasted the whole code now.

Comment: @Hopper, it is the Bootstrap - nothing custom made.

Comment: @user6490375 — http://jsbin.com/silexik/1/edit?html,output — Still can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin, yes, I agree.  But I have posted the image as well.. Maybe that itself is the problem?  Maybe you'll face it if you include Bootstrap CSS as well.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]. Link to the appropriate CSS.

Comment: @Hopper, thanks a ton for the edit.  It makes the question MCV. :)

Comment: @Quentin, please check the new edit by hitting run the code snippet.  You will get the same error that I am facing.

Comment: No problemo !!!

Comment: can you try again after removing <center> around the email / password?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh, yes, I tried that.  But doing so makes the text box occupy the entire screen - from the left end to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did couple of changes,

- Remove the `<center>` tag
- Remove manual width
- Wrap your controls with "row" and then "col-*" div so that your controls move to the center (refer code)
- Add "text-center" to the parent div of
  the control

Does it solve your issue?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>My Website!</h3>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<form>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">         
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email: </span>
        <input class="form-control" align="center" type="text" id="EmailId" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />       
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">        
        <span class="input-group-addon" >Password</span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="PasswordId" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login!</button>
</form>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yes indeed, it does.  Thank you! :)